# Moving string data into new columns where the number of values is arbitrary

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, nlp

I am extracting proper nouns from a column containing string data. I want to move the extracted nouns into a new column as a list (or, alternatively, as one noun per additional column). There are an arbitrary (and sometimes large) number of nouns per entry that I'm extracting.

I've gotten the extraction done and have moved the values I'm interested in to a list, but I can't figure out how to add them on as a column to the case where I extracted them from because of the difference in length between the list I extracted and the fact that it needs to correspond with a single row.

```
    from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer

    data = []
    norm_data['words'] = []
    for sent in norm_data['gtd_summary']:
        sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(sent) 
        data = data + nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent))
        for word in data: 
            if 'NNP' in word[1]: 
                nouns = list(word)[0]
                norm_data['words'].append(nouns)
```

Current Data

```
X   Y
1   Joe Montana walks over to the yard
2   Steve Smith joins the Navy
3   Anne Johnson wants to go to a club
4   Billy is interested in Sally
```

What I want

```
X   Y                                       Z
1   Joe Montana walks over to the yard      [Joe, Montana]
2   Steve Smith joins the Navy              [Steve, Smith, Navy]
3   Anne Johnson wants to go to a club      [Anne, Johnson]
4   Billy is interested in Sally            [Billy, Sally]
```

OR This would be OK too

```
    X   Y                                       Z      L            M
    1   Joe Montana walks over to the yard      Joe    Montana      NA
    2   Steve Smith joins the Navy              Steve  Smith        Navy
    3   Anne Johnson wants to go to a club      Anne   Johnson      NA
    4   Billy is interested in Sally            Billy  Sally        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build up a Series which contains the lists. And after the loop add column Z to the dataframe (I guess your data is in a dataframe?)

```
# Init before the loop
noun_series = pd.Series()
    ...
    # Build up series 
    nouns = list(word)[0]
    noun_series.at[index] = nouns
    index += 1
    ...
# After the loop - add the Z column
df['Z'] = noun_series
```

You need to set the index properly though, such that it matches the correct row.